# Why can’t I send a request to update the token through php?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

```
$ret = file_get_contents('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', false, stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
        'content' => http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
            'grant_type' => $refresh_token
        ])
    ]
]));
```

After running the script, I see a 400 Bad Request error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `\r\n` at the end of the header value definitively looks out of place. If you were passing _multiple_ headers in string form, then there should be a CR LF between each of them, but with just one, I am pretty sure that’s wrong.

Comment: Yes, he still is not needed there

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status
>   code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request
>   due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g.,
>   malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or
>   deceptive request routing).

That means that most likely, something is wrong with the parameters you are sending in the request. That may not be it, but try removing the `\r\n` in your header parameter, they seem odd to me.

```
$ret = file_get_contents('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', false, stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
        'content' => http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
            'grant_type' => $refresh_token
        ])
    ]
]));
```

Comment: It turned out, but the following problem arose. After execution, I see a white screen and var_dump returns nothing

Comment: @jajaja var_dump does not ever return “nothing”. If you mean you get no output at all from a script that should show at least some, then at this point this would probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: If `file_get_contents` just returns `false`, then that’s usually due to the request getting a response with a non-success status code, in that case file_get_contents will discard any response body, unless you explicitly instruct it to behave otherwise (parameter `ignore_errors` set to true in the HTTP context options.)

Comment: I accidentally forgot to remove the exit() line when testing. Now I checked and it gives me an error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Maybe he sends the headers not like this? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#offline What is the best way to check what it sends to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:

```
'content' => http_build_query([
      client_id' => $client_id,
     'client_secret' => $client_secret,
     'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
     'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
 ])
```